# Properly timing CSS animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm building a simple CSS-only loader and it works well except for one thing. It starts out somewhat slow. It goes good, reaches the end is slowing down for a bit.

My animation code:

```
@include keyframes(border-animation) {
  0% {
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid black;
  }

  25% {
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid;
  }

  50% {
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid;
  }

  75% {
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid;
  }
};
```

Example can be found here: http://codepen.io/kinetikc/pen/MwvyxL

Notice how it goes good and when it needs to be going again, it stops for just a split secound.

How can I set the timing right?

Comment: Check this out: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJXWQV Seems to be what you're doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try , changing the timing function of the animation.

http://matthewlein.com/ceaser/

see this link about the timing function,
normally i use the timing function `linear` with loaders and you have `ease-in` you can see how it work in the link

Also you forgot the 100% in the animation,this may influence!

Comment: I tried using both `ease-in` and `linear`, it doesn't do it. I think the problem lies within timing and percentage gaps within animation.

Comment: @TomekBuszewski , i updated my answer , did you finish the animation ?.
You finish the animation in 75%